# Passing eventOption as argument to function

Tags: javascript, events

Module calls a function from other module for registering and de-registering events on elements. I'm passing eventType as an argument. But getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: elementObject.element.EventOption is not a function`

```
elementObject = { element: document.getElementById("elemId"),... }
eventRegisterer(elementObject, addEventListener)
```

Function for event registration:

```
function eventRegisterer(elementObject, EventOption){
    elementObject.element.EventOption('change', changeFunction)
}
function changeFunction() {
  ....
}
```

Why is that storing `addEventListener` as argument is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
function eventRegisterer(elementObject, EventOption){
    elementObject.element[EventOption('change', changeFunction)];
}
```

Using array-like notation instead of directly using property name did work.